# controlling module loading order using a shell script or systemd(fedora) service?

Tags: ubuntu, wifi, systemd, broadcom, modprobe

Using Ubuntu 12.04 with systemd(default). I have a broadcom 4312 wireless card which needs "wl" driver and broadcom NIC which uses "b44" "ssb" modules. now, the problem is, at boot the wireless card is not functioning. for that, I have to remove all related modules viz. wl,b44,ssb etc. later, If I modprobe wl;modprobe b44 - both the devices(Wireless and NIC) works fine. So, How can I modify the kernel module loading sequence such that "wl" loads first followed by "b44"?
Is it worth using /etc/modprobe.d/aliases.conf adding aliases to the modules?
 **or** run a shell script that essentially runs **at the end of startup** running commands:

```
modprobe -r wl b44 ssb
wait 5 (to complete)
modprobe wl 
wait 2
modprobe b44
```

I have no idea to write a systemd or autostart script. if a script works, that is the best option.

Answer (score 1):

From my friend Google who pointed to https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=148170:

/usr/lib/systemd/system/rc-local.service

```
[Unit]
Description=/etc/rc.local Compatibility
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=-/etc/rc.local
#ExecStart=-/pathtoyour/script1
#ExecStart=-/pathtoyour/script2
TimeoutSec=0
StandardInput=tty
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

To enable, run

```
systemctl enable rc-local
```

To run it (not automatically done if you enable it)

```
systemctl start rc-local
```

You can add own scripts with the ExecStart-lines. And you can do your modprobe-magic in /etc/rc.local or your own script.

Comment: But, Ubuntu seems to not have the "rc-local" option. IIRC, Debian defaults into runlevel 2 so is the case with Ubuntu? which means rc2.d  may be the option I need to try?

Comment: Sorry - in fact, Ubuntu already has the rc.local executed at the end. So you just edit `/etc/rc.local` and you're done.